# O certo é "debaixo" ou "de baixo"?

Tags: ortografia

Qual a forma correta de dizer que algo está embaixo de alguma coisa?

**Exemplos:**

- A sujeira está (debaixo/de baixo) do tapete.
- O vizinho (debaixo/de baixo) é mal educado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As duas maneiras estão corretas. Porém são empregadas em situações diferentes, por isso é necessário saber o significado delas.

**debaixo** = Usado para indicar quando algo ou alguém que está numa posição verticalmente inferior.

**de baixo** = Usado com adjetivo, ou quando se correlaciona com a palavra `de cima`.

Exemplos debaixo:

- A Pessoa está debaixo da mesa.
- O Computador está debaixo da cama.

Exemplo de baixo:

- As pessoas andam falando muitas palavras de baixo nível.
- Ele encontra-se no andar de baixo. (Correlacionada com `de cima`)